# install mongodb driver on php7 osx symfony

Tags: php, macos, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have to mongo server running

I installed mongo driver with php like this:

`brew install php70-mongodb`

Added doctrine mongo to composer :
`"doctrine/mongodb-odm": "~1.0.5",
"doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "~3.0"`

When I run composer update

[image]

I already checked that the driver is installed

[image]

I don't understand why is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ODM itself will not support new driver until 2.0 is released, at the moment you can use [alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter](https://github.com/alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter) which implements ext-mongo's API atop ext-mongodb and mongo-php-library. For more informations you may want to see [ODM's last release blogpost](http://www.doctrine-project.org/2016/02/16/doctrine-mongodb-odm-release-1.0.5.html).